# In App Purchase and UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to create an in app purchase which adds functionality with which the user can take a picture.
The app without the purchase doesn't need a camera. To use the in app purchase a front face camera is needed.

Is it possible to set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities for an in app purchase or should UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities be set for the whole app?

I'd rather not use the last option since it will decrease the number of possible users.

Will Apple reject the app if an in app purchase requires more device capabilities than the base app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you test for the device capabilities in the app in the purchase area? Then you don't have to put it in the plist.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    // display purchase button
}
```

Comment: Better late than never :-) Was making this more difficult than necessary.